# How can I understand $\mathrm ds^2 = -c\,\mathrm dt^2 + [\mathrm dx-v_s(t)f(r_s)\mathrm dt]^2 +\mathrm dy^2 +\mathrm dz^2 $ in the simplest way?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, warp-drives

How can I understand this equation $$\mathrm ds^2 = -c\,\mathrm dt^2 + [\mathrm dx-v_s(t)f(r_s)\mathrm dt]^2 +\mathrm dy^2 +\mathrm dz^2 $$ in the simplest way?

I am a 13 year old boy who is totally embarrassed after reading the equation from Harold white's warp field mechanics.

I think you would help me to understand this equation.

Comment: Could you please give some hints on your current knowledge in maths and physics? To start with, do you know Pythagoras' theorem?

Comment: I can really recommend you the book "Spacetime Physics" by Taylor and Wheeler. You can get the scanned version of the 1st edition from Taylor's homepage, if you have no access to the 2nd edition: http://www.eftaylor.com/download.html

Comment: Can you please recommend me a book on quantum field theory?

Comment: First you should have solid knowledge of classical mechanics (in Lagrangian formulation), quantum mechanics and special relativity.

Comment: A description of what?

Comment: Classic mechanics,quantum mechanics and special relativity.

Comment: What kind of description? These theories aren't explained in a comment, actually, each of them is covered by a one semester lecture.

Comment: Like the book you gave to me about spacetime physics,something like that

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know any book for classical or quantum mechanics on the level of the book that I recommended above for special relativity. I know only of standard text books, for QM I'd take Griffiths (http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Quantum-Mechanics-2nd-Edition/dp/0131118927 ), for CM I actually read Landau&Lifshitz, volume 1, but am not sure whether it is recommendable. Actually, both of them require quite a lot of knowledge in mathematics and physics, so please don't be discouraged if you don't understand anything!

Comment: Yeah I understand,i need the basics of all these mathematics and physics stuff.Any pdf?

Comment: Khan academy's videos describe these things

Comment: It was very kind of you,what's your name and profession ?

Comment: My name is Michael and I'm currently finalizing my master studies in theoretical physics.

Comment: What about the book "the concepts and theories of modern physics "by j.b stallo

Comment: I don't know it, unfortunately.

Comment: @Photon what all branches of mathematics is needed to be studied?like trigonometry,algebra and so on .

Comment: Calculus (differentiation and integration, differential equations), linear algebra (vectors and matrices), Fourier series and Green's functions, Taylor series (and the notion of the order of a function), complex numbers. I might miss something, but I think, this is the least that you will need.

Comment: Well, at least these topics are a beginning, there might be some more which are necessary, but you will notice if something is missing once you start studying the physics topics like classical mechanics.

Comment: Sorry I will delete it.now you can also delete it I have saved it,thanks

Comment: Sorry,i hope you read my email.

Comment: Okay,now I've got some solid knowledge in classic mechanics(motion,gravity and stuff like that)Should I study calculus now?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It expresses infinitesimal distance in space-time coordinates.
What's interesting is the long term, representing some kind of wave moving on the $x$ axis.

I assume you know the pythagorean theorem $ds^2 = dx^2 + dy^2$.
Well, this just adds the $z$ and $t$ coordinates.

The long term defines a coordinate that replaces the $x$.
It is a combination of $x$ and $t$, much like a velocity, and combines it into the distance.
It's as if your coordinate system (in which you're measuring distance) were moving along the $x$ axis at speed $v_s(t)f(r_s)$.

Answering comment: The axes are whatever you choose them to be, as long as they're locally orthogonal. You choose the $x$ axis as the direction of movement.
A system moving at velocity $V$ can be described at $dx - Vdt$, meaning if $V=5$, for example, time increases by $1$ and $x$ increases by $5$, it's still the same thing. OK, so what is $V$? It's that funny thing $v_s(t)f(r_s)$ that varies with time $t$, distance $s$, and that function $f$ that depends on $r_s$, whatever that is. So maybe it's slowing down, or speeding up, or something.

Comment: How do we determine x axis ,z axis ? What does vs(t)f(r) says?

Comment: Is this calculus?

Comment: @Nihal: Yes, but not difficult. $d something$ just means "an amount of something that is small enough that you don't have to worry about curviness". Like suppose you have two points on a curvy line close together but not the same point. If the horizontal distance between them is $dx$ and the vertical distance is $dy$, what is the distance on the line between them, $ds$? It's just the square root of the other two distances squared and added together, right?

Comment: Well,I haven't studied calculus yet

Comment: @Nihal: Why not start now? It's fun.

Comment: First let me study all the basics of physics!And I have already started with some linear algebra

Comment: Which is the best book in calculus for beginners?

Comment: @Nihal: the resources are endless! [*Here's a nice one.*](https://betterexplained.com/articles/a-gentle-introduction-to-learning-calculus/)  Also, check out [*Khan Academy*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/intro-differential-calc/v/newton-leibniz-and-usain-bolt).

Comment: Ok,now I have got some idea on Newtonian physics,now,how can I approach to relativity and QM?

Comment: What about Calculus for Dummies ?i already have it!

Comment: @Nihal: I like the "for Dummies" books; I'm sure it's good. For relativity and QM, my favorite is the Feynman Lectures on Physics. Another favorite is Sam Lilley *Discovering Relativity for yourself*. Lilley taught relativity to continuing-ed students like housewives and plumbers, so he really knows how to teach it.

Comment: Well,I had some introduction to calculus but this stuff has everything to do with curve,how can be that something related to relativity or QM?

Comment: I heard it have something to do with tensor calculus,is it somewhat similar to calculus?

Comment: Calculus is all about curves. You can talk intelligently about them by breaking them down into pieces so tiny that each piece is no longer curved. Tensors? That gets beyond what I know. You don't need them for now. They are certainly worth learning, but crawl before you walk, and walk before you run.

Comment: Aren't the necessary for relativity,then what should I lean for relativity?

Comment: Learn things step by step, and don't bite off more than you can chew. Slow and steady wins the race :)

Comment: I just wanna know that what kind of math QM and relativity use!

Comment: If you can, get the Smalley and Feynman references I mentioned above. (There may be others just as good.) When you need some math, learn it. Don't worry about it until you need it. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: According to you,which should I prefer calculus for dummies or khan academy's videos?

Comment: Whichever you prefer...

Comment: Just wanna know which is better,reading will make things stick into brain but that book contains only 387pages where khan academy videos are divided into many sections and with long videos,so am just confused

Comment: if you just look the curriculum of precalculus the you can see a lot of stuff there.but I have a strong bad in trigonometry,do I want to take that part to get other's(differential,integral)?

Comment: It's easy to get a course taught poorly, and it discourages students. I was a teacher, and I've seen it from both sides. I was programming computers before I took my first programming course, which was taught poorly. If I hadn't already been a programmer I would have been discouraged. Math is the same way. Find a problem you want to figure out, teach yourself, and don't get discouraged.

Comment: I think Khan academy is the best place to learn it,btw what did I need to study QM?